# C how to read from valid multiple files?

Tags: c, file, io

Suppose I need to read from given files data, and it can be up to 100 files. 
Let's name it new_FileXX , and XX is a value from 00 up to 99.
Below there is an example of such program  - it's creating an array, opens file in read mode, and prints everything that is written in the file
But it's on reading one file.
The question is: how do I write a function that will read every existing file that named new_FileXX (if it exists of course)?

```
int main()
{
    FILE *ptr_file;
    char buf[1000];

    ptr_file =fopen("input.txt","r");
    if (!ptr_file)
        return 1;
}
```

Comment: Read each file in succession?

Comment: Can't you just open them one at a time to read the data, then close them?

Comment: Something like `FILE *ptr_file[100]; for (...) { sprintf(name, "input%02d.txt", i); ptr_file[i] =fopen(name,"r"); }`

Comment: Take a look at [`sprintf`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/sprintf). You can go in a loop from 0-99, construct the filename during runtime, open it, read it, rinse and repeat.

Comment: @yano Love the [rinse & repeat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lather,_rinse,_repeat).

Comment: @chux Well, what little hair I have left I like to keep super clean ;) Geez, there's a wikipedia entry for everything!

Comment: Please close `ptr_file` after use to dye that hair. Most systems have a limit on how many files may be open at one time.

Comment: There are functions like `opendir()`, `readdir()`, `closedir()` which can scan file names from a directory that are defined by POSIX.  You could use that to read names and there are functions to check whether the name matches shell-style globs — or to do shell-style globbing — also.  You could use some combination of these to find the names that match the pattern you want.  This might be quicker than trying 100 files if most of the files won't be present.  It does I/O on the directory instead of attempting to open the files.

Answer (score -1):

You can try:

```
char filename[256];
FILE *f = NULL;
int i;
for(i = 0; i < 100; i++){
    sprintf(filename, "new_File%02i", i);
    f = fopen(filename, "r");
    if(f == NULL) // file does not exist
        continue; // ignore the rest of the loop for this iteration

    // do your reading here.

    fclose(f);
}
```

`%02i` means print an integer padded over `2` characters (the result will be at least `2` characters long) and use `0` as the padding character (print as much preceeding `0` as possible to acheive the padding `2`).

`sprintf` is like `printf` but instead of showing the result on screen it saves it in a string (`filename` in this case).

`"new_File%02i"` means that the file name should be new_File + a number between 00 and 99. In general it should be `"something%02i.extension"` (I think you forgot the extension).

if `f` is `NULL` then there is something wrong (when using mode `"r"` for `fopen`, it's usually that the file does not exist), so we ignore the rest of the loop where the reading occurs by using the keyword `continue`.